# How to find applications/ports that do bind() but don't do listen()?

Tags: linux, socket, netstat

When a faulty application calls `bind()` with a TCP socket to a port `P` but does not follow with `listen()`, the port `P` is not listed among open ports, i.e. `netstat` or `ss` or `ls /proc/net/tcp` do not show it, but the port is occupied and no other application can use it. Is there a reasonable way to find such applications and such ports?

Comment: Just tested and indeed, I couldn't find this port is in use or what port is used by a known process behaving like this.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the kind of solution that I wanted to rule out as "unreasonable" - going over all processes one by one and check stuff like this (I was thinking also looking into `/proc/X/fd` for sockets that are not mapped elsewhere, I guess that could reveal the process too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until something more suitable is made available, here's an answer that tries in an absolutely non-industrial way to find processes that used `bind(2)` on a TCP socket,  but then did neither `listen(2)` nor `connect(2)`, and can also display what's the bound TCP address.

Requires [`getfattr`](https://manpages.debian.org/attr/getfattr.1) found in a package named `attr` in most distributions plus [kernel >= 3.7](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.7#Networking) to filter out non-TCP sockets, and a minimal installation of [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) (eg on Debian: [`gdb-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/gdb-minimal)). Doesn't require a development environment. Should be run as the *root* user (or else it will find only the same users' information, but this won't even work accross containers). See Caveats at the end.

---

Components:

- A first shell script mimics a part of what would `lsof` do but only for this specific case. Searches all processes for socket FD. For sockets with the property `TCP` or `TCPv6` (which is available as a file meta-attribute `system.sockprotoname` using [`getfattr`](https://manpages.debian.org/attr/getfattr.1), as found with `lsof` that would use [`getxattr(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/getxattr.2) in such manner to at least display it's a TCP socket), check if the (*sockfs* pseudo-filesystem's) inode can be found in their respective network namespace's `tcp` or `tcp6` [proc](https://manpages.debian.org/proc.5) file and if not displays the pid, fd and inode as candidate 3-uple. This script alone will find and list "defective" processes.

  `findbadtcpprocs.sh`:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh

  find /proc -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '[1-9]*' |
      xargs -I{} find {}/fd -follow -type s 2>/dev/null |
          while read procfd; do
              type=$(getfattr --absolute --only-values -L -n system.sockprotoname $procfd | tr '\0' '\n')
              if [ "$type" = "TCP" -o "$type" = "TCPv6" ]; then
                  inode=$(stat -L -c %i $procfd)
                  pid=$(echo $procfd | cut -d/ -f3)
                  if awk '$10 == inode { exit 1 }' inode=$inode /proc/$pid/net/tcp /proc/$pid/net/tcp6; then
                      fd=$(echo $procfd | cut -d/ -f5)
                      echo $pid $fd $inode
                  fi
              fi
          done
  ```

  This script can be used standalone to just find candidate processes without additional information.
- Then a `gdb` script which must be given the right *fd* information. It attaches on a candidate process and will (first allocate some memory in order to) run `getsockname(2)`, display the bound socket (and free allocated resources) an release the process.

  `getsockname.gdb`:

  ```c
  set $malloc=(void *(*)(long long)) malloc
  set $ntohs=(unsigned short(*)(unsigned short)) ntohs
  p $malloc(64)
  p $malloc(4)
  set *(long *)$2=64
  p (int) getsockname($fd,$1,$2)
  set logging file /dev/stdout
  set logging on
  if *((short *) $1) == 2
      set $ip=(unsigned char *) ($1+4)
      printf "%hu.%hu.%hu.%hu",$ip[0],$ip[1],$ip[2],$ip[3]
  else
      if *((short *) $1) == 10
          set $ip6=(unsigned short *) ($1+8)
          printf "[%hx:%hx:%hx:%hx:%hx:%hx:%hx:%hx]",$ntohs($ip6[0]),$ntohs($ip6[1]),$ntohs($ip6[2]),$ntohs($ip6[3]),$ntohs($ip6[4]),$ntohs($ip6[5]),$ntohs($ip6[6]),$ntohs($ip6[7])
      end
  end
  printf ":%hu\n",$ntohs(*(unsigned short *)($1+2))
  set logging off
  call (void) free($2)
  call (void) free($1)
  quit
  ```
- Finally a glue script uses both previous scripts for easy operation. It will avoid uselessly attaching to multiple processes (or threads) sharing the same socket.

  `result.sh`:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh

  oldinode=-1
  ./findbadtcpprocs.sh | sort -s -n -k 3 | while read pid fd inode; do
      printf '%d\t%d\t%d\t' $pid $fd $inode
      if [ $inode -ne $oldinode ]; then
          socketname=$(gdb -batch-silent -p $pid -ex 'set $fd'=$fd -x ./getsockname.gdb 2>/dev/null) || socketname=FAIL
          oldinode=$inode
      fi
      printf '%s\n' "$socketname"
  done
  ```

  Just running this will provide all:

  ```
  chmod a+rx findbadtcpprocs.sh result.sh
  ./result.sh
  ```
- As a bonus a simple reproducer in C source code that will create two processes using the same TCP socket, without using `listen(2)` on it. Usage: `gcc -o badtcpbind badtcpbind.c` and `./badtcpbind 5555`

  `badtcpbind.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>

  #include <strings.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      int sockfd;
      struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
      if (argc < 2) {
          exit(2);
      }
      if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
          perror("socket");
          exit(1);
      }
      bzero(&myaddr, sizeof myaddr);
      myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
      myaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
      if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &myaddr, sizeof myaddr) < 0) {
          perror("bind");
          exit(1);
      }

  #if 0
       listen(sockfd,5);
  #endif

      fork();
      sleep(9999);
  }
  ```

example:

```
# ./badtcpbind 5555 &
[1] 330845
# ./result.sh 
108762  20  303507  0.0.0.0:0
330845  3   586443  0.0.0.0:5555
330846  3   586443  0.0.0.0:5555
```

(Yes for some unknown reason, a `libvirtd` process appears here to create a TCP socket which doesn't get used and is caught in the first line of the results).

---

Caveats:

- a language better than shell should probably be used to allow more readability and efficiency.
- certainly even more racy than `lsof`.
- attaching to a running process the way is done here has issues:

  - doesn't work on a statically linked binary (`malloc()` function or some symbol definitions aren't available then).
  - as no debug information is available, most functions are explicitly scoped and this might not run in all environments without change (tested on *amd64* architecture with kernel 5.10.x, on Debian bullseye, Debian 10 and CentOS 7 userspaces).
  - likewise might not as-is work on a binary linked with an other libc than usual glibc.
  - is intrusive and might crash fragile (especially multi-threaded) applications. Checks aren't done (eg: `malloc(3)`'s or `getsockname(2)`'s failure).
- the last script considers *sockfs* inodes to be globally (rather than per-network-namespace) unique, which I didn't attempt to prove but keeps the script simpler.

Comment: That's... a bit more contrived then I hoped, but I can confirm it works; and the GDB stuff is cool in fact, I would not be able to pull that off myself.